# addor merge fields in array php

Tags: php, arrays, merge, field, addition

this is part of the code:

```
$toExport = array(
            array('c.id_customer','"[quickid]"'),
            array('c.firstname','"[name]"'),
        array('c.lastname','"[lastname]"'),
            array('c.siret','"[hej]"'),
            array('c.email','"[email]"'),
);
```

I would like to merge c.firstname and c.lastname in [name], if thats the correct term?
something like this:

```
$toExport = array(
            array('c.id_customer','"[quickid]"'),
            array('c.firstname + c.lastname','"[name]"'),
            array('c.siret','"[hej]"'),
            array('c.email','"[email]"'),
);
```

I know that that last code is super incorrect, but is it possible to do?

here is the whole code:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
<?php
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
class ExportCustomers extends Module
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->name = 'exportcustomers';
        $this->tab = 'Export';
        $this->version = "1.2";
        $this->author = 'Madman'; //. Based on Willem's module';

        parent::__construct();

        $this->displayName = $this->l('Export customers');
        $this->description = $this->l('Module for export customers to xls file.');
    }

        function install()
        {
                if (!parent::install())
                        return false;
        return true;
        }

    function getContent()
    {
        $this->_html = '<hr><h2>'.$this->displayName.'</h2>';
        $this->_html.= '<p>'.$this->l('This module allow to make a customers xls file.').'</p>';


        $delimiter = "\t";
        $toExport = array(
            array('c.id_customer','"[quickid]"'),
            array('c.firstname','"[name]"'),
            array('c.lastname','"[lastname]"'),
            array('c.siret','"[hej]"'),
            array('c.email','"[email]"'),
            array('c.website','Website'),
            array('c.siret','"[orgno]"'),
            array('c.company','"[Company]"'),
            array('a.firstname','aFirstname'),
            array('a.lastname','aLastname'),
            array('a.address1','"[Address1]"'),
            array('a.address2','"[Address2]"'),
            array('a.postcode','"[zipcode]"'),
            /* array('a.phone','"[phone]"'), */
            array('a.phone_mobile','"[sms]"'),
        );

            /*
ADDRESS FIELDS                      CUSTOMER FIELDS
        id_address                              id_customer
        id_country                              id_shop_group
        id_state                                id_shop
        id_customer                             id_gender
        id_manufacturer                         id_default_group
        id_supplier                             id_risk
        id_warehouse                            company
        alias                                   siret
        company                                 ape
        lastname                                firstname
        firstname                               lastname
        address1                                email
        address2                                passwd
        postcode                                last_passwd_gen
        city                                    birthday
        other                                   newsletter
        phone                                   ip_registration_newsletter
        phone_mobile                            newsletter_date_add
        vat_number                              optin
        dni                                     website
        date_add                                outstanding_allow_amount
        date_upd                                show_public_prices
        active                                  max_payment_days
        deleted                                 secure_key
                                                note
                                                active
                                                is_guest
                                                deleted
                                                date_add
                                                date_upd
            */

        // If we clicked the export button
        if (isset($_POST['exportcustomer'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT ";
            $end = count($toExport)-1; // count keys in array, and remove 1 to compensate for index 0
            foreach($toExport as $key=>$fields) {
                $sql .= $fields[0] . " AS " . $fields[1]; // Add sql
                if($key != $end) { //if not last key
                    $sql .= ", "; // add , to sql
                }
            }
            $file_id = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/id.dat');
            if(!$file_id) {
                $file_id = 0;
            }

            // this sql limits the export to the customers that have address
            $sql .= " FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."customer c, "._DB_PREFIX_."address a
            WHERE c.id_customer = a.id_customer && c.id_customer > $file_id
            ORDER BY a.id_customer ASC";
            // id_customer must be higher then file_id. So if file is 6, customer that is exported will be 7

            $orderlist = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);

            // Create the xls file
            $file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/export_customers.xls', 'w');
                $firstline = "";
            foreach($toExport as $key=>$fields) {

                $firstline .= $fields[1];
                if($key != $end) { //if not last key
                    $firstline .= $delimiter;
                }
            }
            fwrite($file, $firstline."\r\n");
            foreach($orderlist AS $orderline){
                fwrite($file, implode($delimiter, $orderline)."\r\n");
            }
            fclose($file);

            // Get the id of the latest customer
            $sql = "SELECT MAX(id_customer) FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."customer";
            $maxid = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
            $file = fopen(dirname(__FILE__).'/id.dat', 'w');
            fwrite($file,$maxid[0]['MAX(id_customer)']);
            fclose($file);


            $this->_html.= 'Export completed<br>';
            $this->_html .= "Next export will start at customer nr: " . ($maxid[0]['MAX(id_customer)']+1) . "<br><br>";
            $this->_html.= '<a href="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/modules/exportcustomers/export_customers.xls" target="_blank">Download export_customers.xls</a><br>';

            return $this->_html;


        }
        else
        {
            $this->_html .= '<form method="post"><input type="submit" name="exportcustomer" value="'.$this->l('Export file').'" /></form>';
            $file_id = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/id.dat');
            if(!$file_id) {
                $file_id = 0;
            }
            $this-> _html .= "<br>This export will start with customer number: " . ($file_id+1) . "<br><br>";
            $this->_html .='
            <h3 style="margin-top:2em;">'.$this->l('Explanation extraction  :').'</h3>
            <dl>
                <dt><i class="champ">'.$this->l('Custno').'</i> :</dt><dd style="padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 2em;">'.$this->l('Identification customers').'</dd>
                <dt><i class="champ">'.$this->l('Gender;').'</i> :</dt><dd style="padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 2em;">'.$this->l('(1/2) 1 is a man; 2 is a woman and 9 not known;').'</dd>

            </dl>
            ';
            $this->_html .= '<hr>';
            return $this->_html;
        }
    }
}
?>
```